# Increasing the character length of the Title Column in Sharepoint Site

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Is it possible to increase the length of the Title column for a site above the 255 characters.

My requirement is that I use a field that is longer than the maximum 255 chars but because the Title column is a required field I need to enter something in it.  Rather than enter garbage just because I have to, I would like to use it.  If not, then my current thoughts for a workaround will be make a copy of the first 255 chars of a seperate column that I am able to make longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Title column is special. Aside from changing the Display Name there's not much you can do with it. While the Title field isn't used as the database key for the row, it is a logical key when thinking of an item. It should be short and concise. The Title field has the additional functionality of the context menu (Delete, Save Copy, any custom actions, etc.) Having the Title column be quite large could make the UI hard to view. Some users might want to make a custom view without that column pushing the row size too high. In that case, they won't have access to the context menu for that item.

Comment: yep, thats what I figured.  I was hoping that it wasn't so.

Comment: The list is populated from an InfoPath form where the uses enter quite long descriptions. Limiting them to 255 chars might cut out the rather verbose nature of the list and make it more readable as you suggest

Comment: You could always make a summary field that goes to Title and add a field for additional comments/details if the submitted feels they are crucial. You could hide this additional field from the summary list view but still have the information in the item or in a view which includes the extended information.